# Xercesimpl 2.11.0 shows missing in Eclipse Build path though its present in Repository

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, xerces

Though m2 repository has the folder "xercesimpl\2.11.0",  eclipse build path shows, Xercesimpl as missing. I tried as much as i can to resolve the warning but it couldn't solve. Need some help.

**Image1** -  repository where Xercesimpl 2.11.0 resides in the drive

[image]

**Image2** - Eclipse Build path shows Xercesimpl as missing though its present in the repository

[image]